# AttributeError: 'QHoverEvent' object has no attribute 'x'

Tags: pyqt5, python-3.6

I'm trying to show a kind of QToolTip using a QLabel to show the message when the cursor is on a widget in this case a QPushButton

For which it occurred to me to enter an event filter in the QPushButton, and if the event is equal to Hover then it launches the mouseMoveEvent function.

The problem is that the message is shown everywhere but when entering the QPushButton the program stops and throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\Hover.py", line 22, in eventFilter
    self.mouseMoveEvent(event)
  File "C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\Hover.py", line 26, in mouseMoveEvent
    print(event.x())
AttributeError: 'QHoverEvent' object has no attribute 'x'
```

The intention is that the message is displayed only when the cursor enters a widget

this is my code

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QPushButton,QLabel
from PyQt5 import QtCore

class Hover(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.customToolTip = QLabel(self)

        self.button = QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setText("Button1")
        self.button.installEventFilter(self)

        self.setMouseTracking(True)


    def eventFilter(self,object,event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            print("Pressed")
            return True
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.HoverEnter:
            self.mouseMoveEvent(event)
            return True
        return False
    def mouseMoveEvent(self,event):
        print(event.x())

        self.customToolTip.setText("Otro texto")
        self.customToolTip.setStyleSheet("background:red;border-radius:5px;")
        self.customToolTip.move(QtCore.QPoint(event.x(),event.y()))
        self.customToolTip.adjustSize()
        self.customToolTip.show()



app = QApplication([])
h = Hover()
h.show()
h.resize(800,600)
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple but not recommended solution is to change:

```py
self.customToolTip.move(QtCore.QPoint(event.x(),event.y()))
```

to

```py
self.customToolTip.move(event.pos())
```

because the QHoverEvent does not have the method x(), if you want to obtain the position you must use the pos() method.

It is not recommended because you are sending an event to a method that should not be handled, maybe in this case it works but in the future it could bring you problems.

You have the following inadequate phrase in your question: *launches the mouseMoveEvent function*, HoverEnter only triggers when it enters the widget, in the middle it will no longer trigger that event, so it is not the most appropriate if you want to show a tooltip.

If you want the tooltip to be shown only in the QPushButton you must do the following:

- Enable mouseTracking on the button.
- Use the MouseMove event.
- Make the QLabel a child of the button...

```py
class Hover(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Hover, self).__init__(parent)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.customToolTip = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.button)
        self.button.installEventFilter(self)
        self.button.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.button.setText("Button1")

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove and self.button is obj:
            self.handle_tooltip(event.pos())
        return super(Hover, self).eventFilter(obj, event)

    def handle_tooltip(self, pos):
        self.customToolTip.setText("Otro texto")
        self.customToolTip.setStyleSheet("background:red;border-radius:5px;")
        self.customToolTip.move(pos)
        self.customToolTip.adjustSize()
        self.customToolTip.show()
```

The previous method has a drawback since the children of a widget will only be painted at the intersection with the parent, if the text is too long or the mouse is far from the center the QLabel will not be completely displayed, to avoid this you must enable the flag Qt::ToolTip, in addition to convert local to global position using mapToGlobal():

```py
class Hover(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Hover, self).__init__(parent)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.customToolTip = QtWidgets.QLabel(
            self.button, flags=QtCore.Qt.ToolTip
        )
        self.button.installEventFilter(self)
        self.button.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.button.setText("Button1")

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove and self.button is obj:
            self.handle_tooltip(event.pos())
        return super(Hover, self).eventFilter(obj, event)

    def handle_tooltip(self, pos):
        gp = self.button.mapToGlobal(pos)
        self.customToolTip.setText("Otro texto")
        self.customToolTip.setStyleSheet("background:red;border-radius:5px;")
        self.customToolTip.move(gp)
        self.customToolTip.adjustSize()
        self.customToolTip.show()
```

Comment: It should be noted that this doesn't handle hiding the "tooltip", which would be persistent once shown the first time. The simpler solution is to add an else statement against QEvent.Leave hiding the label, which also requires a `gp = self.button.mapToGlobal(pos) + QtCore.QPoint(1, 1)` to avoid flickering. An x value higher than 1 should be preferred also, otherwise the label would be hidden in most cases from a "south-east oriented" mouse cursor.

Comment: Another thing: setting background+border radius never works. It's a known issue, due to x-platform issues Qt has to face: you'll probably never see your rounded bordered background around your widget. The only way is to set a mask: after `adjustSize()` create a new QPainterPath, then `path.addRoundedRect(QtCore.QRectF(self.customToolTip.rect()).adjusted(0, 0, -1, -1).translated(.5, .5), 5, 5)` and `self.customToolTip.setMask(QtGui.QRegion(path.toFillPolygon().toPolygon()))`. It won't be perfect (no antialiasing for masks), but it'll work. Adding `padding: 5px` to the stylesheet is also needed.